# SGoF package: order the adjusted pvalues based on the original pvalues

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am trying to make biological sense of the adjusted pvalues that the function *SGoF* ([R package SGoF](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sgof/versions/2.3/topics/SGoF)) outputs.

**My input** is the pvalues from a [chi-square test on allele count](https://www.r-bloggers.com/chi-squared-test/). Because my actual dataset contains 100,000 of SNPs, I must adjust the pvalues for multiple comparison. I chose the method of Sequential Goodness of Fit and applied to my data.

**The issue** is that the function SGoF outputs the pvalues in increasing order, and therefore I lose the important information (the order of the SNPs), despite naming the vector.

Here is my pretend code on 10 SNPs only:

```
library("sgof")

# create SNP_ID
SNP_ID <- paste("SNP", rep(1:10, 1))
# create original pvalues
original_pvalues <- c(0.7547327676, 0.7759443024, 0.7892817386, 0.5900607320, 0.7085460882, 0.0004190683, 0.6020188578, 0.7898982175, 0.2780472452, 0.6160432682)
# give an ID to each pvalue
names(original_pvalues) <- SNP_ID

# adjust pvalues based on sequential goodness of fit (R package sgof)
sgof_res <- SGoF(original_pvalues, alpha = 0.05, gamma = 0.05)

# oh no, the adjusted pvalues are ordered by increasing values, see:
sgof_res$Adjusted.pvalues

# I would like a table like this:
corresponding_table <- cbind(SNP_ID, original_pvalues, sgof_res$Adjusted.pvalues)
```

Currently the corresponding table does not make biologically sense. How could I create a corresponding table with the following rows: the SNP_ID, the original pvalue and the adjusted pvalue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code of `SGoF` function, we will see it is sorting the pvalues, and outputting the sorted result, too. But, we can also see it outputs `sgof_res$data` which is in the same order as sorted original pvalues:

```
all(sgof_res$data == sort(original_pvalues))
# [1] TRUE
```

So we can do below to get expected output:

```
data.frame(SNP_ID = names(sort(original_pvalues)),
           original_pvalues = sort(original_pvalues),
           Adjusted.pvalues = sgof_res$Adjusted.pvalues)

#        SNP_ID original_pvalues Adjusted.pvalues
# SNP 6   SNP 6     0.0004190683        0.7547328
# SNP 9   SNP 9     0.2780472452        0.7759443
# SNP 4   SNP 4     0.5900607320        0.7898982
# SNP 7   SNP 7     0.6020188578        1.0000000
# SNP 10 SNP 10     0.6160432682        1.0000000
# SNP 5   SNP 5     0.7085460882        1.0000000
# SNP 1   SNP 1     0.7547327676        1.0000000
# SNP 2   SNP 2     0.7759443024        1.0000000
# SNP 3   SNP 3     0.7892817386        1.0000000
# SNP 8   SNP 8     0.7898982175        1.0000000
```